# What is an adjective for a person who is attractive but doesn't like taking care of their appearance?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, slang, colloquialisms

Like an attractive person but who doesn't wear make up, doesn't comb, and doesn't try to combine his clothes.

Attractive in an edgy way, not caring about their look but still looking good. Being handsome without trying. A lazy person who doesn't even do the minimum and still attracts looks towards his/herself.

Comment: Are you looking for a word for somebody who is attractive **because** of not caring (as 'attractive in an edgy way' suggests), or somebody who is attractive **in spite of** not caring ('a lazy person who . . . still attracts looks')?

Comment: Probably different terms for a man or a woman. *Hot mess*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Raffish** (*adj.*) is a possibility.

> not following usual social standards of behaviour or appearance, especially in a careless and attractive way

*He has a certain raffish elegance.*

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/raffish

Answer (score 0):

You can qualify *attractive, attractiveness, beauty, handsomeness, etc*. For example:

**rough-hewn** (adj.)

> Lacking refinement
>
> *He was rather **attractive**, in a **rough-hewn** kind of way* —Jan Speas
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rough-hewn)

**unpolished** (adj.)

> Not polished
>
> *Unpolished gemstones*
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unpolished)

> She was **attractive** in an **unpolished** way and looked her thirty-one
> years.
> [Mary Alexander; *Sum of Her Parts*](https://books.google.com/books?id=TZKkEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT20&dq=%22attractive%20in%20an%20unpolished%20way%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis-pKP5emEAxUEFVkFHUWVDz0Q6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22attractive%20in%20an%20unpolished%20way%22&f=false) (2022)

**rustic** (adj.)

> Lacking in social graces or polish
> [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rustic)

> "I don't know, I thought the boy was rather **attractive** in a **rustic**
> way—quite handsome if you hadn't noticed—but I don't supposed he's
> ever been in a proper drawing room.
> [V.J. Banis; *This Splendid Earth*](https://books.google.com/books?id=CV30AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA175&dq=%22attractive%20in%20a%20rustic%20way%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRo8eX5umEAxULD1kFHfV3B04Q6AF6BAgLEAI#v=onepage&q=%22attractive%20in%20a%20rustic%20way%22&f=false) (2012)